# Why do I get error "ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type"?

Tags: python, sqlite, discord.py, pycord

I get the error:

> ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type

The code :

```
async def add(ctx, el: str, email: str, password: str):
    con= sqlite3.connect("db.sqlite")
    c = con.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT type FROM accounts WHERE type=?", (el,))
    results = c.fetchall()
    if len(results) == 0:
        await ctx.send("there is no type with this")
    else:
        c.execute("UPDATE accounts SET type = ?, email = ?, password = ? ;", {el, email, password})
        print("done")
        await ctx.send("done")
    con.commit()
    con.close()
```

Error trace:

```
Ignoring exception in command add:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 127, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(arg)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 911, in _invoke
    await self.callback(ctx, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Sidtho\main.py", line 42, in add
    c.execute("UPDATE accounts SET type = ?, email = ?, password = ? ;", {el, email, password})
ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type
```

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\bot.py", line 1008, in invoke_application_command
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 359, in invoke
    await injected(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\commands\core.py", line 135, in wrapped
    raise ApplicationCommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.errors.ApplicationCommandInvokeError: Application Command raised an exception: ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type
```

Comment: Are you aware that **type** is a Python built-in?

Comment: it gave me the same error, @PChemGuy

Comment: You need to update the code and error trace

Comment: gave me the same trace, so I will update the code

Comment: No, the trace cannot be the same. Update it

Comment: But I don't understand something. the other things in the code have "type" as element, and it's perfectly working

Comment: I am not saying it was the source of the error here. But never use Python keywords as variable names

Comment: The other way around. Keep only the db code. Remove async calls and make a regular function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel so dumb right now I really wanna cry

the problem is that i did after the c.execute("UPDATE accounts SET type = ?, email = ?, password = ? ;")
I putted a {el, email, password} instead of (el, email, password)...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).